# Entity Framework - SaveChanges not reflected in database

Tags: entity-framework

SaveChanges is not being reflected in the database

I have the following code

```
public async Task<int> Post([FromBody] UserEntry userEntry)
{
    UserEntry dbUserEntry;

    using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
    {
      // update
      dbUserEntry = this.db.UserEntries
                     .Where(u => u.UserEntryID == userEntry.UserEntryID)
                     .Include(u => u.EntryPlayers.Select(y => y.Player))
                     .FirstOrDefault();

      dbUserEntry.TeamName = userEntry.TeamName;
      dbUserEntry.EntryPlayers = userEntry.EntryPlayers;

      //db.Entry(dbUserEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;
      return db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

}

I read somewhere that I need to set the state to modified but if I uncomment the line

//db.Entry(dbUserEntry).State = EntityState.Modified;

I get the error:-

An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Any ideas on how I can get SaveChanges to work?

Comment: is the `this` in `dbUserEntry = this.db.UserEntries`  a typo? because if it's not then that's your issue. You probably have another context define in your controller.

Comment: Have you enabled AutoDetectChanges?

Comment: Thanks SOfanatic. You're right. Copy and paste error from elsewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Find() method instead of FirstOrDefault()

```
dbUserEntry = this.db.UserEntries
                 .Include(u => u.EntryPlayers.Select(y => y.Player))
                 .Find(u => u.UserEntryID == userEntry.UserEntryID)
```